# Problema ao excluir um número de uma lista!

Tags: python, lista, random

Após fazer o sorteio de um numero de uma lista, preciso excluir esse numero da minha lista. porém aparece a mensagem de "list index out of range".
Meu erro se encontra na linha do if. ou há alguma melhor forma de excluir esse numero? lembrando que os outros números que não foram sorteados tem que permanecer na lista para serem sorteados. Já estudei as funções do modulo random, porem nenhum se encaixa para resolver esse problema.

```
import random
import time
Matriz = []
Tamanho_Que_Ficou = 20
Tamanho = 21
Lista_De_Numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
for i in range(3):
    Matriz.append([0] * 7)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(7):
        Numero = random.choice(Lista_De_Numeros)
        Matriz[i][j] = Numero
        for k in range(Tamanho):
            if Numero == Lista_De_Numeros[k]:
                del Lista_De_Numeros[k]
                Lista_De_Numeros = [] * Tamanho_Que_Ficou
                Tamanho_Que_Ficou = Tamanho_Que_Ficou - 1
                Tamanho = Tamanho - 1
print(Matriz)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro `IndexError` está sendo gerado pois você modifica dentro do bloco `if` o tamanho da lista dentro do bloco `for`. Quando o programa obtém um número aleatório, ele o deleta da lista original e após isso ele prossegue com o for loop, onde o `range` está definido com o tamanho da lista antes de ter o número deletado.

A solução para resolver este erro foi adicionar `break` no final do bloco `if`. Dessa forma ele iria parar a execução do bloco `for`. O problema é que depois disso ele gera o seguinte erro:

> IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Este erro ocorre porque na linha `Lista_De_Numeros = [] * Tamanho_Que_Ficou` a sua lista de número fica vazia. Eu não entendi o motivo de você ter escrito isto, mas para corrigir este erro, eu precisei apagar essa linha.

O código corrigido ficou assim:

```
import random
import time

Matriz = []
Tamanho = 21
Lista_De_Numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

for i in range(3):
    Matriz.append([0] * 7)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(7):

        Numero = random.choice(Lista_De_Numeros)
        Matriz[i][j] = Numero

        for k in range(Tamanho):
            if Numero == Lista_De_Numeros[k]:

                del Lista_De_Numeros[k]
                Tamanho = Tamanho - 1

                break
print(Matriz)
```

Existem também algumas coisas que você pode fazer para diminuir este código.

- Não é necessário você verificar número por número para enfim deletar o valor obtido da lista. Existe um método de lista chamado `remove(value)` que apaga o valor da sua lista.
- Você pode utilizar [compreensão de listas](https://www.vooo.pro/insights/tutorial-compreensao-de-listas-python-com-exemplos/) para não precisar escrever os números da lista de números manualmente.

**Código melhorado:**

```
import random
import time

Tamanho = 21

Matriz = [[0]* 7 for i in range(3)]
Lista_De_Numeros = [number + 1 for number in range(Tamanho)]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(7):

        Numero = random.choice(Lista_De_Numeros)
        Matriz[i][j] = Numero
        Lista_De_Numeros.remove(Numero)

print(Matriz)
```

Comment: Sou iniciante em python, porem seu código ficou bem mais pratico. pesquisei e não encontrei esse comando "remove". Obrigado!